# Get the property and values from object

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have a code that sends a request to an api and return values and deserialized them to an object.
I made it an object cause we don't limit to calling it to 1 api only and we can expect an ODATA, collection, string etc as a response.

```
var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(strValue, httpRequestExtras); 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(httpResponse.ResponseString);
```

sample response was

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "test 0"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

normally when I get properties and values from an object i used reflection.
`response.GetType.GetProperty("items")`

but with the code above, i can't get the property "items" in the object response as I'm getting a null value. [image]

not sure if it has to do with the type as JObject from newtonsoft deserializing.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest using generics instead, that way you can have generic code but pass in a class as an object for deserialization and you're not dealing with `object`.  Strongly typing and being more specific on the deserialization will be better in the long run.

Comment: hi, I can't use generics as I'm only using it for 1 class.

Comment: That doesn’t make any sense but anyway. See the answer, it’ll that’s how you deal with JObject.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion though. hard to explain the requirement but it's all good now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JObject instead of object. Then you can get the JProperty "items".

```
string json = "{\"items\":[{\"id\":0,\"name\":\"test 0\"},{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"test 1\"}]}";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);
if(result != null)
Console.WriteLine(result.Property("items"));
```